# Fetching a value from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to fetch a value from a table in my database into a placeholder for an html input element. Code is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="timesats" placeholder="
    <?php
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/paycheck/scripts/connect.php');
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        $sql = "SELECT timesats WHERE email='$user'";
        $query= mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
        echo($result);
    ?>
">
```

`$dbc` contains the values for connection. 
I'm getting no errors so its really hard to debug. The value from the table is not null.

Comment: Your SQL is wrong!!! You need to `SELECT column(s) FROM tablename WHERE limiting factor` [READ THE MANUAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/paycheck/scripts/connect.php');
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  $sql = "SELECT timesats WHERE email='$user'";
  $query= mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
  while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
    $ph = $obj->timesats;
  }    
?>
<input type="text" name="timesats" placeholder="<?php echo $ph; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Getting this error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Check my edited answer to see if it works now.

Comment: read the question, then answer

Comment: it works now. witht his code and the changed SQL code. thanks buddy

Comment: @RiggsFolly why are you assuming i didn't read the question?

Comment: @Mindastic - I assume it's because the SQL in your question will generate a syntax error.